# DAX Percentage of Count with Conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in power bi in which I have the hours of entry to work. The case is that I can make a table that collects for each hour of work the number of people who have entered at that time with the count function.

See an example:

```
entry time
09:30          
09:30          
09:22
```

In other words, in the table values field I drag entry time and entry time count, which gives me for each entry time the number of people that entered.

The case here is that I would like to create a measure that allows me to obtain the percentage of people who have entered at 9:00 and 9:30 with respect to the total.

```
[(Number of people that have entered at 9:00)+(Number of people that have entered at 9:30)]/ count of people that have entered
```

I've unsuccessfully tried to create a measure.

Comment: What happens to those who entered at 9:22? From your "sample data" it seems you are looking for (X + y) / (X + y + z), right?

Comment: Hi @Peter is not counted since I am only interested in those who have entered at 9:00 and 9:30 a.m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your table just contains the times when people entered on separate rows. You can count the Timestamps directly with the following measure:

```
% Count = 
VAR selected = 
    CALCULATE(
        Count('Table'[Time]),
        'Table'[Time] = TIMEVALUE("9:00")
        || 'Table'[Time] = TIMEVALUE("9:30")
    )
VAR allpeople =
    CALCULATE(
        Count('Table'[Time]),
        ALL('Table')
    )
RETURN 
    DIVIDE(selected, allpeople)
```

[image]

Comment: Ignore the ID column. It's needed only to show all data rows.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Peter! It does not return the correct result. I suspect why but I don't know how to correct the code you have proposed. Your column "sum of people" I calculate it in a table with a count of "time". How can I correct this?

Comment: The data returns the correct results with the data I posted. You didn't share any sample data so I can't see what you're looking at.

Comment: I just edited the post to make it clearer. I would appreciate if you could check it out

Comment: Your edit didn't help much but I tried again ...

Comment: I have tried both options and nothing... I don't understand it.

Comment: I think that the first option that you proposed was right on track, what happens is that I can not do the sum of a value that is not numerical (time), I would need the sum of the times that time has appeared.

Comment: But that is the same as counting the timestamps, see above.